# Configuring AWS S3 Frontend and Lightsail API on Google Domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, web-deployment, amazon-lightsail

I don't have a lot of experience with routing so I'm looking for some general guidance on configuring my S3 site and Lightsail API to use the same domain.

I own a domain from Google Domains, `example.app`.

I set up the repo for my API on AWS Lightsail and listed the custom name servers on my Google domain. This all worked fine, my API endpoints (`example.app/api/v1/`) are working.

I have set up my frontend in an S3 bucket and have the Amazon-provided domain, `http://example.app.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`. I want this to also use the domain `example.app`.

My question is, how can I set this up? It seems like I can't list the name servers from both the S3 website *and* the Lightsail API under my Google Domains. Do I need to do some of my own custom routing, or use a subdomain like `api.example.app` for the API?

I'm trying to avoid combining them into one full stack app because the API is used by multiple clients.

Answer (score 1):

At this point you have given them both the same domain name (example.app). There is no way to configure that in DNS to support both of these on the same domain. Your options are to either change the domain name of the API server to something like api.example.app, or place something in front of both things that can route the traffic according to the path being requested.

I highly recommend going with the second option, and using a CDN like CloudFront or Cloudflare in front of both servers. You would point example.app to the CDN service, and configure the CDN to send requests with the `/api` path to your Lightsail server, and send all other requests to your S3 bucket.

You get a lot more benefits from using a CDN, like SSL (you can't do SSL if you serve files directly from S3 without a CDN), and response caching.

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to try out the CloudFront option. Thank you so much Mark!